# CASE WHEN with aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I can't understand the purpose of the query using conditional function :"CASE WHEN with aggregate functions"..
1. what is the purpose of the aggregate function in this causes ?
2. what is the difference between putting the aggregate function inside the sentence for example: case when max()..
compared to max(case when...)
Below: find the columns include null values in the table that the rows known.

```
SELECT *   
FROM (  
   SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(customer_id) IS NULL THEN 'customer_id' ELSE NULL  END ) AS 'Name' FROM customers   
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(customer_name) IS NULL THEN 'customer_name' ELSE NULL  END ) FROM customers   
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(customer_address) IS NULL THEN 'customer_address' ELSE NULL  END ) FROM customers   
   UNION ALL  
   SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX(customer_age) IS NULL THEN 'customer_age' ELSE NULL  END ) FROM customers  
   ) tbl  
WHERE tbl.Name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Looks like an odd way to check if a column only contains `NULL` values and to unpivot that data into a single column in the result set. The above probably isn't the most efficient way to do it, as it requires 4 scans of the table `customers`. If you don't understand the reason for the way the query was written, have you spoken to the author of it?

Comment: `CASE WHEN MAX(column) IS NULL` effectively checks that a column either has no values or they're all `NULL`. `MAX(CASE WHEN (...))` would be a completely different beast, actually calculating the maximum of whatever expression you put in the `WHEN` (which could not be a boolean expression, as SQL Server doesn't allow boolean expressions in that context).

Comment: This is really good explanation .I ישהק wasted all they to understand the difference and the logic behind the query. @Jeroen Mostert